# JavaFx Control Skin: layout the only child as if my control inherited from it

Tags: javafx, adapter, skin

I have an interface like this, that I use in a lot of places in the project:

```
public interface ValueHoldingControl<T> {

    T getValue();

    ObjectProperty<T> valueProperty();

    void setValue(T value);
}
```

I need a version of [this DateTimePicker](https://github.com/hemeroc/javafx-datetimepicker) that implements `ValueHoldingControl<LocalDateTime>`. Since all of the methods declared in my interface are already implemented in the DateTimePicker from the repository, and they have `LocalDate` as their type, I cannot use inheritance to achieve this.

This is my current version (parts irrelevant to my problem are omitted):

```
public class ComposedDateTimePicker extends Control implements ValueHoldingControl<LocalDateTime> {

    private static class ComposedDateTimePickerSkin extends SkinBase<ComposedDateTimePicker> {
        private ComposedDateTimePickerSkin(ComposedDateTimePicker control) {
            super(control);
            getChildren().add(control.dateTimePicker);
        }
    }

    private final DateTimePicker dateTimePicker = new DateTimePicker();
     
    @Override
    protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
        return new ComposedDateTimePickerSkin(this);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime getValue() {
        return dateTimePicker.getDateTimeValue();
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(LocalDateTime dateTimeValue) {
        dateTimePicker.setDateTimeValue(dateTimeValue);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectProperty<LocalDateTime> valueProperty() {
        return dateTimePicker.dateTimeValueProperty();
    }

}
```

**The problem**: When I layout my `ComposedDateTimePicker` from the outside (e.g. `composedDateTimePicker.setMaxWidth(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY)`), this does not have any effect on the internal `DateTimePicker`.

I can solve that for the width if I override `layoutChildren` of my `ComposedDateTimePickerSkin` like this:

```
        @Override
        protected void layoutChildren(double contentX, double contentY, double contentWidth, double contentHeight) {
            ((ComposedDateTimePicker) getNode()).dateTimePicker.setPrefWidth(contentWidth);
            super.layoutChildren(contentX, contentY, contentWidth, contentHeight);
        }
```

I could do the same for the height. However, I don't like this way of doing it, since it is not a general solution.

I would like to do it in a way that no matter what kind of layouting setting I apply on my `ComposedDateTimePicker`, it behaves as if it was inherited from `DateTimePicker`.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: generally, it's the task of the skin to do the sync of all properties - that said: I can't really imagine how you want to use this new control, feels like layout might be the least of your problems

Comment: I'll assume this is an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info) until proven otherwise.  *"I need to have a method called exactly getValue() that returns a LocalDateTime instead of a LocalDate"* -> Why?  A date picker picks a date, not a date and time.  The implementation you have has no notion of time, that I can tell (other than the class name).  If it really does pick times too, then you are probably omitting of lot of potentially useful stuff from the question.

Comment: I think I agree with @jewelsea. This is an XY problem. As noted, a `DatePicker` has no notion of time. But if you need a `LocalDateTime`, and don't particularly care about the time, then you can simply do `datePicker.getValue().atStartOfDay()`. Or you can create a separate "time picker" control (this can be done as a custom control--created by you or provided by a third-party library--or simply a group of controls that work together). Then do e.g., `LocalDate date = datePicker.getValue(); LocalTime time = timePicker.getValue(); LocalDateTime ldt = date.atTime(time);`.

Comment: I just presented it in this way to focus on the problem I want to solve. The full version would be that I want to have a control like this: https://github.com/hemeroc/javafx-datetimepicker , but in order to properly integrate that with the rest of the code and its interfaces, I cannot have an extra method called `getDateTimeValue()` (like in the repository), but I need a method `getValue()` that gives me the LocalDateTime.

Comment: I updated the question to better reflect my purpose.

Comment: In general, you are applying an [adapter pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern#:~:text=In%20software%20engineering%2C%20the%20adapter,be%20used%20as%20another%20interface.). I have no advice on the specifics at this time. The linked article might provide some implementation ideas and standard naming advice for such a pattern.